# UIAlertView animation freeze

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have in the past seen a `UIAlertView` freeze momentarily during its animation, but not have anything else onscreen freeze (such as when deleting apps from a device...the other apps keep on wiggling).  In my app right now I've got a `UIAlertView` freezing for a moment partway through its animation, but the Time Profiler in Instruments doesn't show the kind of CPU usage that would freeze the UI, and I can see other things happening in the UI behind the alert.  What could cause this?

Comment: Does your app have an open gl view or any sort of graphics related stuff going on?

Answer (score 2):

Often this type of thing is caused by showing the alertView in the action method of some control. If this is your case, use a dispatch block that shows the UIAlert (which you can prepare in the action routine), and dispatch it async to the main queue.

Comment: This answer was very helpful in solving a serious performance problem.

Comment: In my case I didn't notice the alert was being shown from a background thread

Comment: @chuckSaldana, trust me, you are not the first person to do this :-)